# Terrain tessellation and depth buffer

Tags: c++, directx, directx-11, depth-buffer, tessellation

I am doing some terrain rendering and I've run in the some troubles. At this point in time I am just tessellating vertex patches then displacing them with a height map. My current problem is that the rendering looks pretty funky. I've been debugging this for a while and it looks like it is a problem with the depth buffer. Past that, I don't really have any ideas on what is happening.

Here's an image of the depth buffer i grabbed using VS graphics debugging. Wasnt really sure the best way to show this using the debugger so I grabbed an image of the red channel and the green channel
[image: 1]
[image: 1.5]

Here's backbuffer
[image: 2]

As I understanding it, closer pixels should be colored darker than further pixels. As you can see when comparing the second and third images, it seems like the opposite is happening. Am i misunderstanding something or is something weird happening.

Any thoughts or pointing in a direction would be very appreciated since I'm out of ideas.

I'll post how I am setting up my depth buffer for possible questions:

Here's how I am setting up my depth stencil state and raster state:

```
D3D11_DEPTH_STENCIL_DESC dsdesc;
ZeroMemory(&dsdesc, sizeof(dsdesc));

dsdesc.DepthEnable = true;
dsdesc.DepthWriteMask = D3D11_DEPTH_WRITE_MASK_ALL;
dsdesc.DepthFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_LESS;
dsdesc.StencilEnable = true;
dsdesc.StencilReadMask = 0xFF;
dsdesc.StencilWriteMask = 0xFF;
dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_INCR;
dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsdesc.FrontFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;
dsdesc.BackFace.StencilFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsdesc.BackFace.StencilDepthFailOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_DECR;
dsdesc.BackFace.StencilPassOp = D3D11_STENCIL_OP_KEEP;
dsdesc.BackFace.StencilFunc = D3D11_COMPARISON_ALWAYS;

HR(_device->CreateDepthStencilState(&dsdesc, &_depthStencilState));

D3D11_RASTERIZER_DESC rd;
rd.AntialiasedLineEnable = false;
rd.CullMode = D3D11_CULL_BACK;
rd.DepthClipEnable = true;
rd.DepthBias = 0;
rd.DepthBiasClamp = 0.0f;
rd.FillMode = D3D11_FILL_SOLID; 
rd.FrontCounterClockwise = false;
rd.MultisampleEnable = false;
rd.ScissorEnable = false;
rd.SlopeScaledDepthBias = 0.0f;
```

and then I am indeed using them

```
_context->RSSetState(_rasterStateWireframe);
_context->OMSetDepthStencilState(_depthStencilState, 1);
```

Here's how I am setting up my depth buffer:

```
depthBufferDesc.Width = clientWidth;
depthBufferDesc.Height = clientHeight;
depthBufferDesc.MipLevels = 1;
depthBufferDesc.ArraySize = 1;
depthBufferDesc.Format = DXGI_FORMAT_D24_UNORM_S8_UINT;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Count = 1;
depthBufferDesc.SampleDesc.Quality = 0;
depthBufferDesc.Usage = D3D11_USAGE_DEFAULT;
depthBufferDesc.BindFlags = D3D11_BIND_DEPTH_STENCIL;
depthBufferDesc.CPUAccessFlags = 0;
depthBufferDesc.MiscFlags = 0;
```

EDIT:

Adding a couple more images, maybe show the issue a little better:

[image: img]
[image: img]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

K solved the issue. I had the the near plane and far plane flipped when creating the perspective projection.